# mongodump archive vs gzip

Tags: database, mongodb, backup, database-backups

When using `mongodump` there's two options listed in the docs regarding compression: [`gzip`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/program/mongodump/#cmdoption-mongodump-gzip) and [`archive`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/program/mongodump/#cmdoption-mongodump-archive).
What's the difference between the two? Can / Do I want to use them in conjunction or are they mutually exclusive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `--archive=filname` option will output a single file instead of creating a directory structure with each each collection in a separate file.

The `--gzip` option will make the output file(s) be compressed with gzip.

They can be used separately or together.

Comment: Sorry for being a little unprecise with my question. Here's some additional ones. The archive isn't a gzip archive? What format is it in? Doesn't this mean `--archive` will apply some form of compression already?

Comment: No, using `--archive` is like using `tar`.  It combines multiple files and paths together into a single archive file.  Compression is a separate operation.

Comment: Okay so if I understand you correctly, tar archives don't apply compression by themselves but only "group" all files into a single one to put it into simple words? That I didn't know.